# VSCode with Multilanguage Monorepo

Tags: visual-studio-code

For better or for worse, the project I support at my organization has consolidated to a single repository of about 30 different projects (20 C/C++, 7 Java/Javascript, and 3 Python). Each project is generally standalone, but some implement interfaces defined in another project.

I have become a fan of using Visual Studio Code on CentOS 7 for source code editing. I want to ramp this usage up to have intellisense hooks for the C/C++ code, build tasks, etc. I can create the .vscode and the various json files at the top level; however, the root level of the repository does nothing more than organize the projects.

What is a recommended way to manage this? Should I create a .vscode in each project that is customized to each project, and will the intellisense configuration and tasks be available at the root level of the repository?

Comment: I've faced a similar issue and I've created a small vscode-extension that colors the tab based on a regex, so to help you avoid confusion when you're working on a file. So you can say `.java => red` for example.
Check it out:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=orepor.color-tabs-vscode-ext